# Get memory usage information with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Is there any generic way to get memory usage information (total memory used by the tab process/thread or heap size, something like that) in javascript? 
I want to be able to have user-agents periodically report memory usage back to the server so that I can tie specific user actions to possible memory leaks. I can imagine there are security implications of this, but just curious to know of anything was out there, even if it worked only for the release versions of chrome or firefox (I can't seem to find anything).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible. JavaScript has no access to system data like that.

Comment: To browser add-ons, it's possible. To regular sites, probably not.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Firefox, the memory reporters are available to installed extensions. The important starting point is the [`nsIMemoryReporterManager`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIMemoryReporterManager) interface implemented by the "@mozilla.org/memory-reporter-manager;1" service.

Comment: Cool. Unfortunately, I likely won't be able to get users to install an extension. But its helpful to know that worst case, I could get power users to install an extension that could collect this data. Thanks!